# Shutting down when using Intent on tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, android-tabhost, shutdown

I created a tabHost with 3 activities, so when I click on the tabs, I change the activity.

This is the code of the first activity:

```
public class estadisticas extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.estadisticas);
    // TABS

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(estadisticas.this, clasificacion.class);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(estadisticas.this, novedades.class);
    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.mytabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    //tab 1
    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("estadisticas");
    tab1.setIndicator(getString(R.string.statistics),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.estadisticastabs));
    tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);

    //tab 2 
    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("clasificacion");
    tab2.setIndicator(getString(R.string.scores),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.estadisticastabs));
    tab2.setContent(intent1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);

    //tab 3
    TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("novedades");
    tab3.setIndicator(getString(R.string.whatsnew),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.estadisticastabs));
    tab3.setContent(intent2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);

    // END TABS
```

And I get shutdown when I click both (or tab2 or tab3).

Where am I wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your basic understanding of TabHost is not correct. All the Tabs (tab1, tab2, tab3) of a TabHost are in Activity estadisticas, so something else is causing the crash. Show me your Logcat.

Comment: have you added activities in manifeast file?

Comment: Yes I got my activities in the Manifest file.
This is my LogCat:


04-18 17:51:47.877: D/AndroidRuntime(3330): Shutting down VM

04-18 17:51:47.888: W/dalvikvm(3330): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)

04-18 17:51:47.888: E/AndroidRuntime(3330): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

04-18 17:51:47.906: E/AndroidRuntime(3330): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?

Answer (score 0):

you missing these 2 lines

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
```

try this code :

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tab);
           // LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //if (!locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){


           //     }

           // SetupTabs();
            Resources res = getResources(); 
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
            Intent intent;

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Addplace.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("BYM").setIndicator("By Manually",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_unselected)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

           // createGpsDisabledAlert();
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HelloAndroidGpsActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("BGPS").setIndicator("By GPS",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_unselected)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
          //  }


            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, mapclass.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("BYM").setIndicator("By Map", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_unselected)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

          //  tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

        }
```

Comment: you extended your activity from TabActivity ? if not then extend your class from TabActivity like this **public class Add_tab extends TabActivity**

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you said in English

Comment: @RafaFirenze  I can't get on my main activity (this)  what does it mean?